# Mailing to remote domains not supported

Tags: raspbian

I tried to email out from my Raspberry Pi 3:

```
pi@igla:~ $ cat /etc/debian_version 
8.0
pi@igla:~ $ uname -a
Linux X 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@igla:~ $
```

and I got following response back:

```
Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  X@gmail.com
    Mailing to remote domains not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

### Remote Domains

"Mailing to remote domains is not supported"
You should make sure that there's a real Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) installed on your Pi.

I usually install `postfix`.

Comment: I believe `Raspbian` comes with `Exim`.

Comment: I thought so too, but I just checked a fresh install of 2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie and `exim4` was not installed.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the exim configuration in Debian may disable proper functioning of the MTA:

```
# fgrep remote /var/log/exim4/mainlog.1 | sed -E 's#([ <])[^ <]+@[^ >]+([ >])#\1a@b\2#g' | head -1
2019-01-08 00:47:00 1ggebk-00055M-St ** a@b <a@b> R=nonlocal: Mailing to remote domains not supported
#
```

It can be enabled by running the following, and selecting the `internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP` option within the `ncurses` dialogue:

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Note that although the top option says accept mail from the internet, it would appear that even if selected, by default it's limited to the localhost IPv4/IPv6 addresses for accepting the mail, so, it would seem that you don't really have to worry about opening up the `smtp` port on the server to the outside world just by selecting the option (TBH, it then makes little sense why it's not even the default).

Comment: I believe that's what I was looking for, although I cannot check it as I'm away, but +1 anyways)

Comment: @alexus, I believe it's probably the same; I looked over my /var/mail/`whoami` on my Debian machine, and the text of the returns I have appears to be identical to the one you provided in the original answer, so, I'm willing to bet it must be coming from `exim4`.